# Variable is incremented by 2 threads without synchronization

Tags: java

In an interview, I was asked a question that a variable is incremented 200 times by 2 threads without synchronization, what s the maximum and minimum value of variable?
Please could someone help me with the answer.

Type of variable int.
Each increment is of 1.
Initial value is not told to me.

Comment: Minimum? Unknown. Maximum? Unknown. If it's an `int` then `Integer.MIN_VALUE` and `Integer.MAX_VALUE`.

Comment: @BoristheSpider The update of an `int` is atomic, so you can't get corrupted values. An update may be overridden, resulting in the loss of an increment, but that's all.

Comment: I guess it's `i++` @AndyTurner - in which case there are all sorts of visibility and concurrency issues.

Comment: @Andreas I think his point was it depends upon the starting value too.

Comment: @AndyTurner Then he should say so. The question is about the effect of unsynchronized access, and comment suggests that anything can happen, which is not true.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Considering the no of increments of 200 and assuming each increment is of 1 and type of variable int my guess is:-

- Max= variable current value+ 400,
  Considering worst case scenario where 1st thread incremented the value 200 times and then 2nd thread incremented it by 200 times.
- Min= variable current value+2

  1. Thread1 & Thread2 copy variable.
  2. Thread1 increments 199 times. so variable
     becomes variable + 199
  3. Thread2 increments once. so variable becomes variable +
     1
  4. Thread1 copies variable (value = variable + 1)
  5. Thread2 increments 199
     times. so variable becomes variable + 200
  6. Thread1 increments once. so variable
     becomes variable + 2

The max and min will is dependent on variable current value and each increment size, here assumed it be 1.

Answer (score 3):

The interesting problem here is that this interview question is open-ended.

The only sensible way to answer this question in an interview is to narrow down the unknowns.

- Do you know the type of variable to begin with?  It'd be awkward to increment a `short` by a `long`.
- Do we know what the variable *starts* at?  It could start at `Integer.MIN_VALUE` for all we know, and thus the "max" could be a very very small number.
- Do you know how much the variable is being incremented by?  Incrementation *assumes* +1, but that may not be the case.

**This is how you would answer the question without getting into implementation details**; be sure that you narrow down the requirements and get specific details of scope and starting expectations before you attempt an answer.

To the actual coding part of this, consider that either thread could see stale data.  There's no guarantee that the variable will increment anything beyond the number of times you're invoking it (multiplied by your increment value), so there *is* a hard ceiling and floor.  Both depend on you disambiguating the unknowns.

Comment: You missed the first question to ask: What is the *type* of the variable? "Increment" implicitly says it's numeric, but is it `byte`, `short`, `char`, `int`, or `long`, and for increments other than default of 1 as done by increment operator: `BigInteger`, `float`, `double`, `BigDecimal`.

Comment: And if it's `long` or `double` then there are bigger problems. `BigDecimal` would be a disaster...

Comment: Given simplicity of question, I do however think it's fair to make the assumption that initial value is 0, type is `int`, and increment is done using increment operator (`++`). Stating those assumptions in an answer would of course be prudent.

Comment: @Andreas:  That's the point of the interview.  **Never assume.  _Always_ ask clarifying questions.**

Comment: @BoristheSpider `long` or `double` *may* be problematic, since there is no *guarantee* of atomicity, but for modern processors they would be. But why is `BigDecimal` a disaster? It is immutable, and reference variable updates are atomic.

Comment: @Makoto Depends on format of "interview". If written, you can't ask for clarification, in which case you make assumptions, and document them. It could also be that questioner doesn't know answer to clarification question.

Comment: @Andreas:  If you can't get clarification, walk out immediately.  That's not a position you want to be in.  If you can't ask for clarity on a requirement you're given in an *interview*, they're not going to give you that privilege when you're actually working for them.  But now we're getting off-topic.

Comment: True, I should have asked more questions.